# Draw text on UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

So I'm hoping someone here has dealt with this before and can guide me. What I'm trying to do is draw some text on top of an image. My problem is that images can be so many different sizes to the point that the text is either huge or tiny. Everything I'm finding says to pick a font size and it will give me the size of the rectangle to draw it in. That doesn't work for me, I want to calculate the size of the rectangle, and figure out the correct font size to fit that rectangle. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Thanks in advance, I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

If UILabel is used to add text into UIImage, consider the Autoshrink feature. You need to define the maximum font size based on the sample image's width. Here is a sample code.

```
func addTextToImage(image: UIImage, text: String) -> UIImage? {
        
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: 45.0))
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = UIColor.black
        label.text = text
        
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25)
        label.numberOfLines = 1
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true


        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, false, 0)
        imageView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        label.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let imageWithText = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return imageWithText
    }
```

Here is the Output:
[image]